# Why my CMake does not add CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS?

Tags: c++, cmake

I suppose that using cmake with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` adds appropriate compiler flag to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.
However, once I typed the following command and then see the content of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, nothing expected was added.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
```

Below is the snippet of my CMakeLists.txt.

```
... #version and project name
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3")
message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

From the message, I expected it to show `-Wall -g3`.

But what was shown was only `-Wall`, seeming that `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` was not added to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` as opposed to the explanation given in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html.
It says that 

`For example, in a build tree configured to build type Debug, CMake will see to having CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG settings get added to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS settings. See also CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES.`

In my case, which one was indeed used, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`?

Comment: Instead of resetting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` you should **add** your settings to the existing settings, i.e. do a `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")`

Answer (score 1):

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is just a variable. You set `-Wall` to the variable, so `-Wall` is what the variable contains.

The documentation is misleading. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` is not added *into* the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` *variable*. The content of  `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` is added to the *content* of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable, and the result is given to the compiler (not stored in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable).

> In my case, which one was indeed used, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG?

Both are used in your case (assuming CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is case-insensitive).

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is used for all builds and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` is used when `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

---

The author of a CMakeLists.txt file should avoid modifying these variables and instead use `target_compile_options` if necessary.

Comment: If I may also add, the `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` variables are independent of each other - neither is used to initialize the other.

Answer (score 1):

CMake does not merge your `_FLAGS` variables immediately at the CMake *configure* stage (when you print the variable using `message()`). Instead, you can see how CMake treated these settings by running:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

then examining the output to see if the appropriate flags are being passed to the compiler.

In general, manually manipulating the `_FLAGS` variables like this is discouraged. When necessary, it is typical to *append* your flags (as commented) to the existing flags, rather than **over-writing** them:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
```

However, with newer versions of CMake, it is best practice to apply compilation flags using a target-based approach. This aligns well with sound, object-oriented, software engineering principles, rather than setting flags in a blanketed manner. As such, you could use [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) to set these flags where appropriate instead:

```
target_compile_options(YourTarget PRIVATE 
    -Wall 
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-g3>
)
```